# Statistics about consecutive visited days

Tags: support, profile-page, statistics

I was looking for a statistics about consecutive visited days, is there any public data which can been seen. Does it require the *new*  [site analytics privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/site-analytics)?

Comment: For yourself, or for other people?

Comment: Of other users to compare it.

Comment: No, you can't see other people's visit data, and it's not in the site analytics either.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I know that I cannot see it of other people which is fine. I was asking for statistical data.

Comment: @rekire What kind of stats are you looking for?  I might be able to pull something but you need to be a bit more specific about what you want.

Comment: I would like to know how many users reached e.g. 30, 100, 200, 300, 365, 500, 750 or 1000 consecutive days. The first two values are easy to find out, but not the rest of the values.

Comment: @rekire I'll take a look in the DB and see what I can find just give me a few days since it's the weekend.

Comment: In the range of 2468 consecutive days, I'd wager there won't be more than 5 people (see comments of http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/122976/6309). And if you have anyone with *more* than 2468 (at this current day)... they are delusional or confused ;)

Comment: @VonC that makes me sad just 1577/925 from me :(

Comment: @rekire that is still impressive. More important than this statistic is the quality of one's contribution.

Comment: It is 902/66 for me, not really impressive

Comment: To calculate your nerd level take the square root of the average consecutive days you've spent on the site.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Consecutive visited days isn't public information but I can provide you with some high-level stats.

We have 4 users who have visited the site 2469 consecutive days.

Most users visiting consecutive days are in the less than 30 day bucket, but here is a full breakdown of current stats:

```
Consecutive Days Total Users 
---------------- ----------- 
2000 - 3000      8           
1000 - 2000      65          
750 - 1000       58          
500 - 750        119         
365 - 500        106         
300 - 365        66          
200 - 300        288         
100 - 200        931         
50 - 100         2626        
30 - 50          3626        
< 30             5224223
```

As requested, I attempted to recreate historical stats. These are the stats for the maximum consecutive visited days for users.

```
Consecutive Days Total Users 
---------------- ----------- 
2000 - 3000      9           
1000 - 2000      118         
750 - 1000       135         
500 - 750        416         
365 - 500        582         
300 - 365        556         
200 - 300        2104        
100 - 200        14328       
50 - 100         28709       
30 - 50          69937       
< 30             5117004
```

Comment: I wonder if the [Community](http://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community) user counts as one of the 4 users.

Comment: @MageXy Nope, the community user doesn't register days. It's a bot and can do whatever it wants.

Comment: @bluefeet Fair enough, though I was curious since it does have "Member for x years" and "last seen" stats.

Comment: This is the current stat, right? Do you have historical data available that would allow to calculate the maximum consecutive days ever reached per user, and make a histogram from those?

Comment: @Bergi I was able to pull together the historical stats for each user.  Feel free to histogram it to your hearts content.

Comment: 2469 days === 6 years, 39 weeks and 5 days (or 9 months and most of 4 days)

Comment: @ToniLeigh: Wow! I really call shenanigans on that being a real user performing manual visits, to be quite honest.

Comment: So in the end, `Fanatic` badge is too easy to get ? :-) (and yet I don't have it !)

Comment: @PreferenceBean it seems extreme, but there are extreme programmers out there - I'd also consider someone who has the tab pinned in all their devices, where just turning the computer on might refresh the page - plus, you can retrieve this data and games are powerful things, people [like](http://www.guinnessworldrecords.com/world-records/longest-marathon-basketball-dribbling) [extreme](http://edm.com/articles/2015-06-06/irish-dj-breaks-record-200-hour-set) [achievements](http://www.recordholders.org/en/list/ball.html) :-)

Comment: @ToniLeigh: Yeah, I'd call that counting as shenanigans because it's not really _using_ the site

Comment: @PreferenceBean nope, no shenanigans for me: actual visit, with actual participation (at least one answer a day to keep the bugs away)

Comment: @VonC: Every single day for almost seven years?? That's crazy. Hope you're getting some sunshine too!

Comment: @PreferenceBean As I documented before (http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/122976/6309): every. single. day.

Comment: @VonC: I'm impressed. You never fancy a holiday?

Comment: Holiday @PreferenceBean? I was active on the site on my wedding day!

Comment: @PreferenceBean both (Stack Overflow and holiday) are not incompatible. Here is an answer I wrote at Alcatraz, waiting for the boat to bring me back to shore: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16469646/6309

Comment: @PreferenceBean And here is the photo to prove it, complete with EXIF metadata: https://goo.gl/photos/9RM2XJ1PYRXCZX7r5

Comment: @VonC as I say, some people like extreme acheivements!!

Comment: and I have to say, 14500 answers is actually 6 per day for that entire time - nevermind fanatic badges, there ought to be a Guiness Record

Comment: Hmmm... is one of those users Community? 'Cause that guy really gets around. ;)

Comment: @JDB Nope, all real people no bots allowed.

Comment: @bluefeet: in the spirit of Cinema Sins: "*That's racist*" (ding) and sigh: I'm disappointed in myself for getting only 2032 days consecutively. *Darn*.

Comment: Your stats are wrong though. I gave up on the consecutive badge. I'm on everyday at least once, *but* I've noticed that if I have it already in my browser from previous day, or if I use this app, I don't get credit, even if I answer a question. Only credit I get is when I close my browser and reopen it to this site. I've literally been on at least once a day every day for the last three years, but it never goes higher than a few days then resets for some reason.

Comment: @SpYk3HH One possibility is that you don't know that we measure days in UTC rather than local time. So it may be that you are missing days because of that. Another possibility is that you need to click a question rather than just refreshing the front page to the best of my knowledge. Try clicking a question every UTC day and see if that works.

Comment: @jmac i'm actually trying again and so far noticing it lasting longer. i'm trying different things to test where the holes might be. I do know, for fact, that last year, there were several days i was only using app and never got credit, despite making comments, and upvoting answers, but i havn't tested just using app yet. I also remember one weekend in which i submitted answers 2 days in a row, but only got credit for being on a sat, but that was about 2-3 years ago. So. i'll keep experimenting for now and update you if i see a conflict. i'm taking notes this time

Comment: @SpYk3HH sounds like you need to read up on [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) -- that should solve the bulk of your problems.